# Как добавить 1 изображение на несколько видео Python?

Tags: python, видео, png, mp4

Суть такова, у меня есть папка с видео, в количестве 200 штук, нужно на все эти видео добавить картинку по центру и сделать на ней прозрачность 70% (Картинка всего 1 для всех видео), подскажите как это можно реализовать

Answer (score 0):

Установить `ffmpeg`, и запустить данный код:

```
import os
import ffmpeg

logo = './logo.png' # Картинка
folder = './videos/' # Путь до папки с видео

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    # Проверяем что это `.mp4`-видео
    if filename.endswith('.mp4'):
        input_video = ffmpeg.input(folder + filename) # Загружаем видео в ffmpeg
        overlay = ffmpeg.input(logo).filter('transparency', transparency=0.3) # Создаём маску-картинку
        out = ffmpeg.overlay(input_video, overlay, x='W-w/2', y='h-h/2') # Накладываем маску
        out.output(folder + 'out_' + filename).run() # Сохраняем результат. `out_` - префикс выходного названия файла
```